# How to get crash dump on Handled Exception?

Tags: windows, debugging, crash-dumps

My dll is used by a module which dirtily catch all exceptions and just log it in to a file.

My issue is that there is an access violation in a customer site which is reproducible only on its computer and I want get able this customer to generate a dump file for this issue.

I tried to generate an AV in my dll and generate a dump file using adplus but no dump where created since the AV is catched by the module which use my dll.

So my question is:

Is there a way to generate crash dump file even on handled exception?

Thanks,

Yann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ADPlus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265629.aspx), you can read more about configuring ADPlus [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163530.aspx) (Minidumps for Specific Exceptions)

Your config file will look something like this:

```
<ADPlus>
  <Settings>
    <RunMode>CRASH</RunMode>
    <Option>Quiet</Option>
  </Settings>
  <Exceptions>
    <Config>
      <Code>AllExceptions</Code>
      <Actions1>FullDump</Actions1>
    </Config>
  </Exceptions>
</ADPlus>
```

Comment: Thanks.
i didn't know anything about adplus configuration file, it looks very useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Vista SP1 and later the Windows Error Reporting service can be configured to produce crash dumps whenever an application crashes:

Under the registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]

Define values:

- DumpFolder (REG_EXPAND_SZ) - where the dump files are stored
- DumpType (REG_DWORD) - 2 for full dump, 1 for mini dump

This works for both 32-bit and 64-bit programs. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181.aspx

Comment: The problem I see here is that a handeled exception don't crashes the process.